# Mozfullscreenchange event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, mozilla

My Code:

```
$('#divid').on('mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange', notify);

$('#divid').bind('mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange', notify);
```

`webkitfullscreenchange` works as expected, but `mozfullscreenchange` seems to do nothing.

`.bind` doesn't help either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide some background on what your end goal is?

Comment: i need to know when user left fullscreen to validate input infos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the last comment [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724816):

> the event is fired at the document, not at the element that goes full-screen

They also say it is documented [on mozilla developer pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Notification).

So put the listener on a `document`, not on the element.

Comment: thanks! :) i read that in mozz developer guide, but, for some reason don't do in my code. Tanks a lot!

Comment: @AllanFelipeMurara as long as this was a correct answer could you please mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to simon, i forgot the moz documentation.

final command :

```
   document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", notify);
   document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", notify);
   document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", notify);
   document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", notify);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari and Chrome needed this to detect the exit of fullscreen:

```
  video.addEventListener('webkitendfullscreen', function () {
    // do stuff here
  }, false);
```